# Add missing years and corresponding values into arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I've been messing around with the JBChartView library and it seems really good for charting. It's easy enough to use but i'm having some problems getting my data in a format that i need for a particular chart.

The user can enter a value and corresponding year. This is saved using core data. The data could look like as follows:

Year: 0 Value: 100
Year:2 Value 200
Year 3 Value 150

I would create 2 arrays, 1 for the year number and another for the value. in this case though, I would get 3 bars. What i'd like is a bar with value 0 for Year 1.

I think the best way to approach this would be to look through the Year array, check to see if the first value is 0, then check if every consecutive year value is +1. If not, add 1 to the previous year and insert a value of 0 into the values array at the same index position.

I would like to know if this is the best approach and if I could get some help doing the comparison.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got to an answer to my own question and thought i'd post it as it may help someone in the future, especially when creating charts using this, or other libraries.

I first populate 2 mutable arrays

```
chartLegend = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@1,@3, nil];
chartData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"100",@"300", nil];
```

So i've got years 1 and 3, each with an associated value in the chartData array.

i now need to create a year 0 and year 2 so that my bar chart has a bar for every year from 0 to my maximum year, 3.

```
- (void)addItemsToArray {

for (int i=0; i<[chartLegend count]; i++)
{


    //get the values from our array that are required for any calculations
    int intPreviousValue = 0;
    int intCurrentValue = [[chartLegend objectAtIndex:i]integerValue];

    if (i>0)
    {
        intPreviousValue = [[chartLegend objectAtIndex:(i-1)]integerValue];
    }



    //Deal with the first item in the array which should be 0
    if (i == 0)
    {
        if (intCurrentValue != 0)
        {
            [chartLegend insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] atIndex:i];
            [chartData insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] atIndex:i];
        }

    }

    //Now deal with all other array items
    else if (intCurrentValue - intPreviousValue !=1)
    {
        int intNewValue = intPreviousValue +1;

        [chartLegend insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intNewValue] atIndex:i];
        [chartData insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] atIndex:i];
    }




}


//create a string with all of the values in the array
NSString *dates = [chartLegend componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSString *values = [chartData componentsJoinedByString:@","];

//display the text in a couple of labels to check you get the intended result
self.yearsLabel.text = dates;
self.valuesLabel.text = values;
```

}

That seems to be working for me. It should be easy enough to populate your arrays using coreData information, just make sure it's sorted first.